# decimal has been truncated when insert into redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have create a table in redshift database, such like

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
   "field1"              decimal(8,3)
)
```

Then I try to run the following SQL

```
insert into abc ("field1") values (666.666);
```

But finally I just found the value in the table become 666.66

Please help.

Comment: How are you displaying that value? Maybe your SQL client only displays two decimal digits?

Comment: You can test if this is only display problem by using something like: `select * from abc where field1 = 666.666;` Let us know this does not return anything.

Comment: we just went through the same idiotic thing...loading, reloading, dropping the table, recreating it, scouring the docs for the secret hidden problem with creating decimal fields...only to find that it was the stupid, stupid, idiotic default behavior of the DB client displaying only the 1st 2 decimal places. Pure genius.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally got the answer.

I am using Workbench for the SQL client, and it default show 2 decimal place only. I have to change it inside the options setting.

Answer (score 1):

To change the default of just two decimal digits, change the SQLWorkbench's data formatting. This can be achieved by

```
Preferences -> Data Formatting -> Decimal digits -> to 3 (based on the above example).
```